# How add new library via NPM?

Tags: node.js, angular, ecmascript-6

I have angularjs2 app.
I want to add new library. I have installed library, so now I have:

1. node_modules/angular2-token - some files
2. "angular2-token": "0.0.3" - in package.json

How add Angular2TokenService to use it ?
In app.component.ts I try add:

```
import {Angular2TokenService} from 'node_modules/angular2-token/angular2-token.js';
```

or

```
import {Angular2TokenService} from 'angular2-token';
```

Add to component providers: [Angular2TokenService]

And constructor

```
 constructor(private _tokenService: Angular2TokenService) {
        this._tokenService.init({
            apiPath: '',
            signInPath: 'auth/sign_in',
            signOutPath: 'auth/sign_out',
            validateTokenPath: 'auth/validate_token',
            updatePasswordPath: 'auth/password',
            userTypes: null
        });
    }
```

What I forgot to add ?

**UPDATED**
package.json:

```
{
  "name": "aspnet",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typings": "0.8.1",
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.9",
    "angular2-token": "0.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

systemjs.config.js (but I don't find where I include it):

```
(function(global) {

  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular'
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'boottodolist.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };

  var packageNames = [
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    '@angular/router-deprecated',
    '@angular/testing',
    '@angular/upgrade',
  ];

  // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  }

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

in index.html I have this part:

```
System.config({
    map:{
        'angular2-token': 'node_modules/angular2-token/angular2-token.js'
    },
    packages: {
        app: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
```

error:

> http://localhost:56597/node_modules/angular2-token/src/angular2-token.service
>   404 (Not Found)

Comment: Which angular2 version you are using? Can you also share your package.json and systemjs.config.js files?

Comment: Missing here // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'boottodolist.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };

Comment: I can't understand what I should add. I have added 'angular2-token':             'node_modules/angular2-token', to map and 
    'angular2-token': { main: 'angular2-token.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }, to packages

Comment: Updated system config js

Answer (score 0):

Import Angular2TokenService into your component

```
import { Angular2TokenService } from 'angular2-token';
```

Add Angular2TokenService as a provider to your component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    providers: [Angular2TokenService],
    templateUrl: './app.html',
})
```

Inject Angular2TokenService into your component and call .init()

```
constructor(private _tokenService: Angular2TokenService) {
    this._tokenService.init();
}
```

See if this helps.

---

**EDIT:**

Your map and packages section of systemjs.config.js file should look like this-

```
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
      var map = {
        'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
        '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
        'angular2-token':             'node_modules/angular2-token'
      };

      // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
      var packages = {
        'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-token':             { main: 'angular2-token.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
      };
```

Sample index.html for your reference-

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes. it should be work, but I did something with app... now I get Observable errors.

Comment: If this issue is resolved then close this one and raise new one for Observable errors.